# Will someone become a disbeliever/kafir by watching shows or reading books which have elements of shirk/kufr in it's name?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, kufr

Assalamualaikum , If someone reads books , novels or watches anime's , shows , web series , tv serial etc which have elements of kufr or shirk in their name or in the name of a certain episode/volume will the person become a kafir or a mushrik by reading or watching them?

Answer (score 0):

Becoming a kafir/disbeliever has solely to do with the intentions of that person. If you just watch it for entertainment then obviously it is not shirk. But instead if you actually believe in anything that has shirk in it, then that is surely kufr.

> Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) once said "The reward of deeds depends upon
> the intention and every person will get the reward according to what
> he has intended." (*Sahih Bukhari, Kitab-ul-Imaan, Hadith No. 53*)

This hadith itself clears many misconceptions that we mostly have.